# "Attribute provided with no value" when runing a simple HTTP request script with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-headers, httprequest

I'm trying to run a simple HTTP request with the following script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var USERNAME = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('XXXXXX');
  var PASSWORD = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('XXXXXXX');

  var url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('https://myurlapi');

    var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };

  var params = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":headers,
  };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

When running the script I have the following error `Attribute provided with no value: url (line 16, file "Code")`

Line 16 is `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);`

I've positively tested the API with https://www.hurl.it/ and It's working. so what's wrong with my script ?

Comment: `I have the following error` - which line of your code triggers that error?

Comment: can you `console.log(url)` just before `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);` - what do you get

Comment: `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);`

Comment: my guess is that `var url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('https://myurlapi');` results in something other than what you expect

Comment: yes the issue is probably here but I don't know what to do...

Comment: ok, what **is the value of url** perhaps you are using [properties service wrong](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148651/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, It's working with the following script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var USERNAME = 'XXXXXXX';
  var PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXX';

  var url = 'myurlpi';

    var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD),
    "Accept" : "*/*",
  };

  var params = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":headers,
    "validateHttpsCertificates" :false
  };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I basically get rid of of the `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty`.

Would love to understand why ? :)

Comment: are you literally saying `getProperty("mypassword")` or are you saying `getProperty("mypasswordkey")`? Im wondering because you censored it in your first post too